# ThinkingSphinx: association field UPDATE does not reindex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

```
thinking-sphinx (3.3.0)

Rails 5.0.4
```

I have troubles with updating associations - ThinkingSphinx (apparently) does not reindex them.

**model1**

```
class DocRequest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :doc_responses, :inverse_of => :doc_request, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**model2**

```
class DocResponse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doc_request, :inverse_of => :doc_responses
end
```

**app/indices/doc_response_index.rb**

```
  ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :doc_response, :with => :active_record, :delta => true do
    indexes doc_request.title, :as => :doc_request_title, :sortable => true
    indexes text

    has doc_request_id
  end
```

Controller:

```
result = DocResponse.search @keyword
```

When I update the `title` of a `DocRequest` model (in Admin area), ThinkingSphinx obviously does not reindex the `doc_request.title` field, e.g. the `result = DocResponse.search @keyword` query doesn't change.

What's wrong?

Running `rake ts:rebuild` solves the problem. But I can't do it on every update.

I tried to add a

```
  ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :doc_request, :with => :active_record, :delta => true do

    indexes title

  end
```

index and then to perform directly `result = DocRequest.search @keyword` - it **worked correctly**. But that's surely not what I need.

**db/schema.rb**

```
 create_table "doc_requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.boolean  "paid"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.boolean  "delta",      default: true, null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_doc_requests_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "doc_responses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "chosen"
    t.text     "text"
    t.float    "price"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "doc_request_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    null: false
    t.boolean  "delta",          default: true, null: false
    t.index ["doc_request_id"], name: "index_doc_responses_on_doc_request_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_doc_responses_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

What did I do wrong? I need some help.

Can I enable some verbose console mode in ThinkingSphinx - to see the reindexing events while updating? That might be useful for debugging.

I quess that the answer is somewhere near this http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/deltas.html#deltas-and-associations , but what exactly to do - I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking Sphinx does not automatically detect your associations and how they relate to your indexed data whenever you make an update to your models, as that could potentially be *very* complex (and thus, slow).

You've linked to the exactly correct part of the documentation, though it's slightly out of date - you'll want to use `after_commit` instead. Whenever you have a DocRequest updating, you'll want to set the delta flags for all of the associated DocResponse objects:

```
class DocRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  after_commit :set_response_delta_flags

  # ...

  private

  def set_response_delta_flags
    doc_responses.each { |response|
      response.update_attributes :delta => true
    }
  end

  # ...
end
```

Updating each response will fire off the delta processing for the affected response objects, which will in turn ensure their Sphinx data is up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I noticed another problem: why when I use the search keyword "tested" I get the results including the "test" word? This is wrong, I'd like to get rid of it.

Comment: Do you have any stemming/morphology set up? That's probably the cause of that.

Comment: development: &generic
  mem_limit: 128M
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 3
  morphology: stem_enru
  charset_table: "0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, @, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+451, U+451"
  max_matches: 100000
  per_page: 100000

  charset_type: "utf-8"
  expand_keywords: 1

production:
  <<: *generic

Comment: Yeah, the `morphology` setting is what enables the matching on similar words (test/testing/tested, etc). If you don't want that happening, you should remove that setting and rebuild.